# Struggling with image upload from my iOS to my PHP server

Tags: php, ios

The code below is used to upload image to a remote server, but for a certain reason it does NOT work for me.
When I enter, for example to this page and I use the php form to upload image, it works with no problem.
So, concerning the PHP part, there is no single problem and everything is working.

### The Question :

What's wrong with that ?

> ```
>         NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageViewer.image, 90);
>         NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/post_image.php";
>            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
>                 request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
>         [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
>         [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];           
>         NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
>         NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
>         [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];           
>         NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
>         [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>         [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>         [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>         [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
>         [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>         [request setHTTPBody:body];            
>         NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>         returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>         NSString *picture = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>         NSLog(@"uploaded picture: %@", picture);
> ```

Comment: Is the server expecting `application/octet-stream` or `image/jpeg` ? What you send needs to match what is expected - so what is expected?

Comment: Well, actually : image/jpeg. Should I try to change it ?

Comment: It's a start towards a solution ;-)

Comment: Really great solution !! it is working now, but the problem is that it is uploading the image 2 times !! so it posts on the folder 2 pictures, any ideas on what is causing the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mime type to match what you're actually sending (`image/jpeg`).

Delete one of these duplicate lines:

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

(and probably at least log the error parameter...)