# Uploading image data using POST php ios

Tags: php, ios

Here is the code..

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {   
    UIImage *yourImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
    NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[imageData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://address/foldername/upload.php?"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:imageData];
    NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];   
    if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
}
```

connection logs Succesffull but im missing something i don't know what

Here is the php
I think the problem may lye here

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root" , "");
if(!$con){
    die('Could not connect' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("Databasename",$con);

//upload your file
$uploaddir = './Uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "/uploads/{$file}";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body data you send should include more information:

```
[imageData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"name.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[imageData appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

So that the server knows what it received and how to handle it. Be sure to create `imageData` as mutable.

Comment: thanks for reply, ive made the changes, replaced jpeg with png but still no luck

Comment: Debugged / checked logs in the server? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763838/struggling-with-image-upload-from-my-ios-to-my-php-server for sample code (with different content type and boundary)

Comment: tried everything i can, i logged the response and im getting undefined index userfile

Comment: Are you setting it anywhere in your upload details?

Comment: Yes here - Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; ... is this the right place?

Comment: What is `['tmp_name']`? (I don't use php much)